# mongodb difference between resident memory and virtual memory

Tags: mongodb

I run Mongo version 4.0.4 on vm with Rhel7, 1 Gb buffer cache is configured.
The resident memory is a little higher than 1 GB, virtual memory 3Gb, why such a difference between resident memory and virtual memory?

Answer (score 1):

This is not only normal, but is on the low side of the difference. On my machine right now `mongod` processes use about 2 GB of virtual memory and <200 MB of RSS.

Virtual memory is consumed by *reservations of address space* which are not necessarily backed by physical memory. As a result the amount of virtual memory that a process uses may be very large, and easily exceed the total amount of physical memory in the machine.

See for example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/138427/what-does-virtual-memory-size-in-top-mean).